# I 'denied' ruby access to the internet and want to 'allow' instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions

I am installing rails and creating a test application via

```
 $> rails server
```

but when I was asked to allow ruby to communicate with the internet, I accidentally clicked 'deny'. How can I take this back and 'allow' ruby to communicate across my firewall? Retrying the command

```
$>rails server
```

causes the terminal to freeze up after the line

```
[2014-09-11 19:12:04] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1641 port=3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to delete this question, because I feel rather stupid now... but I thought I'd post an answer instead.

Terminal didn't 'freeze up' because it was having trouble accessing the internet, it merely deferred activity to a new window because it spawned a browser process, i.e., opened the welcome page of my test website.

Comment: You never know who may have the same problem and stumble upon your question and answer.  You did the right thing to leave your question and post your answer.